# Use dedicated network while uploading files to Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've written a small .NET code which daily uploads a couple of files (about 50 GB each) from Amazon EC2 instance to Amazon S3.

Just for the reference, this is the snippet:

```
public static bool UploadFiles(string s3bucket, IEnumerable<string> filesToUpload)
{
    TransferUtility FileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(S3Client);
    bool bSuccess = true;
    foreach (string fileToUpload in filesToUpload)
    {
        try
        {
            FileTransferUtility.Upload(fileToUpload, s3bucket);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bSuccess = false;
            Mailer.SendMail("Cannot upload " + fileToUpload + " to " + s3bucket, GetFullStackTrace(ex));
        }
    }
    return bSuccess;
}
```

The problem I'm facing currently is that the **network is used to maximum** during upload due to which other services provided by my server is disrupted.

Is it possible to have a dedicated network between Amazon services: EC2 and S3 so that upload file consumes only that network and my usual internet facing network is unaffected?

Comment: what instance size are you using?

Comment: The problem as described doesn't sound quite right.  A single upload to S3 should not overwhelm other traffic, no matter how large or how long it runs, due to network saturation.

Comment: I'm using m3.medium instance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to configure a "dedicated network between Amazon services".

The closest such capability is using Amazon EC2 with **EBS optimized** activated. This provides additional network capacity that is used solely for communicating with the Elastic Block Store (EBS) service.

**Network bandwidth out of Amazon EC2 instances varies by size of instance**. Small instances have less bandwidth than large instances. For a comparison, I copied 3GB of data on an m1.xlarge instance (with large bandwidth) and it took 30 seconds via the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI) using multi-part upload.

In normal circumstances, your networking stack should allow multiple channels of communication (not just sending the file to S3), but sending 50GB files would certainly consume a large portion of the bandwidth.

Comment: I have EBS-optimized enabled in my instances. Copying a 50 GB file from c3.large instance takes about 2 - 3 minutes. So my Web Services becomes unavailable (or one can say very very unresponsive) for 5 minutes every time I start the backup.